# Store geofire query results in hooks

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, geofire

Hi I have been stuck in a React Function useState and geofire. I just want to learn hooks and useState, but I can not have any progress even struggling too much to find a solution.
here is my database component code which is throwing an error

```
import "firebase/database";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const geofire = require("geofire");

const firebaseConfig = {
  //my config
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const userKey = "slg3";

const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("users/place");
const geoFire = new geofire.GeoFire(firebaseRef);

// geoFire.set(userKey, [26.71, 88.43]).then(
//   function () {
//     console.log("Provided key has been added to GeoFire");
//   },
//   function (error) {
//     console.log("Error: " + error);
//   }
// );

let geoQuery = geoFire.query({
  center: [26.71, 88.43],
  radius: 0.001,
});

const database = () => {
  const [pos, setPos] = useState([]);
  geoQuery.on("key_entered", function (key, location, distance) {
    setPos((prev) => [...prev, location]);
    console.log(
      key +
        " entered query at " +
        location +
        " (" +
        distance +
        " km from center)"
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="location">
      {pos.map((item) => {
        return <h1>{item}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
export default database;
```

I am trying to render an h1 everytime a location is returned from geoQuery.on(). I am trying to store locations to state variable but I getting an error as **“Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.”**
I am using geofire for queries.
Please help and Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My query is solved. I have shift this code inside useEffect hook.

> Initial code:-

```
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function (key, location, distance) {
    setPos((prev) => [...prev, location]);
    console.log(
      key +
        " entered query at " +
        location +
        " (" +
        distance +
        " km from center)"
    );
  });
```

> Changed code:-

```
useEffect(() => { geoQuery.on("key_entered", function (key, location, distance) {
    setPos((prev) => [...prev, location]);
    console.log(
      key +
        " entered query at " +
        location +
        " (" +
        distance +
        " km from center)"
    );
  });},[]);
```